# Shiny: How to refer to a randomly generated dataset without it being regenerated?

Tags: r, shiny, regression

I drafted this app to show the effect of skewed residual. Users get to specify the intercept, slope, sample size, and residual skewness.

The output is a scatter plot. And I'd like to add a regression output. However, I cannot figure how to write the part:

```
  output$reg01 <- renderPrint({
  summary(lm(1:10~rnorm(10)))
```

Currently I just stuff a fake regression there to make sure my UI at least works okay. But ultimate I want it to read y and x from myData; I tried lm(y~x, data=myData) with no success. As if the myData is confined in the first renderPlot() function.

Any help on how to keep a simulated data constant within each run, so that I can use different plot/tabulate function to refer it? My guess is something about reactive() but I am not sure how to put a dataset in it.

```
library(shiny)
library(sn)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId= "n", "Sample size", value=100),
  numericInput(inputId="b0", "Intercept",   value=2.5),
  numericInput(inputId="b1", "Slope",       value=5),
  numericInput(inputId="skew", "Skewness",  value=0),
  plotOutput(outputId = "scatter"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "reg01")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    # Creating the data
    x   <- rnorm(input$n)
    res <- rsn(n=input$n, xi=0, omega=15, alpha=input$skew)
    y   <- input$b0 + input$b1*x + res
    myData <- data.frame(x,y)
    # Generating the plot
    plot(x,y,pch=16,col="#00000050")
    abline(input$b0,input$b1,col="#FF000040",lwd=10)
    lines(loess.smooth(x,y,span=0.6),col="#00dd55",lty=3,lwd=4)
    abline(lm(y~x),col="#4488aa",lwd=4)
  })
  output$reg01 <- renderPrint({
    summary(lm(1:10~rnorm(10)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Here is a minimal (non-)working example without all the statistical details:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId= "meanX", "mean for x", value=10),
  numericInput(inputId= "meanY", "mean for y", value=10),
  plotOutput(outputId = "scatter"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "reg01")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    # Creating the data
    x   <- rnorm(100, input$meanX, 1)
    y   <- rnorm(100, input$meanY, 1)
    myData <- data.frame(x,y)
    # Generating the plot
    plot(x,y,pch=16,col="#00000050")
  })
  output$reg01 <- renderPrint({
    summary(lm(y ~ x, data=myData))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want yet. So, the problem isn't that you don't know how to display the output, right? The problem is something about it being "regenerated". I might know what you mean, but I'm not sure. Can you clarify?

Comment: Certainly. In the "server" code, I created a scatter plot "output$scatter" using a data set generated within. I want to add some statistical output right under, calling the same data set. I don't want to paste the data simulation code into the "output$reg01" again, fearing that it'd randomly create a totally different data set. Hope that helps and thanks!

Comment: @Hack-R, thanks! I added a minimal error-generating example with the statistics trimmed down. How can I get the data show up at the bottom? Thanks!

Comment: Just add the following line `assign("myData",myData, envir = .GlobalEnv)` after `myData <- data.frame(x,y)`.  Have a look here (related issue): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531633/var-model-with-exogenous-variable-doesnt-work-in-shiny/50532780#50532780

Comment: If you want `myData` to be automatically update as well then you need a reactive expression for your dataframe

Comment: @antonioACR1, thanks! This works as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the data generation into a reactive container. Reactive values can be used to generate other outputs or reactives. They only recalculate if their inputs change.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId= "meanX", "mean for x", value=10),
  numericInput(inputId= "meanY", "mean for y", value=10),
  plotOutput(outputId = "scatter"),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "reg01")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  mydata_storage = reactive({
    # Creating the data
    x   <- rnorm(100, input$meanX, 1)
    y   <- rnorm(100, input$meanY, 1)
    myData <- data.frame(x,y)
  })

  output$scatter <- renderPlot({
    mydata = mydata_storage()
    plot(mydata$x,mydata$y,pch=16,col="#00000050")
  })

  output$reg01 <- renderPrint({
    mydata = mydata_storage()
    summary(lm(y ~ x, data=mydata))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the hint on storing it as a frame. I did not know reactive() can do that!!